# How do I make the Managed Navigation menu appear the same on all pages

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata

Apologies if this is amazingly obvious somehere...

I've implemented a SP2013 Publishing Site and enabled the friendly URLs and Managed Navigation.  For what it's worth, I've also used the Starter Pages from Randy and opted for the HTML file option to do my branding.  This all appears to work nicely.

It seems that when you use the top navigation menu to drill down into a term/page, it will then appear empty and have no links.

Is it possible to have the same menu as the top level (with the dropdowns etc) appear on all pages?

Comment: Oh there it is :|

In the master page (HTML)...

On the <PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource> tag there is a property called StartFromCurrentNode which when set to false achieves the same menu on all pages.

    <!--SPM:<PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource ID="topSiteMap" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider" StartFromCurrentNode="false" StartingNodeOffset="0" ShowStartingNode="false" TrimNonCurrentTypes="Heading"/>-->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the master page (HTML)... On the  tag there is a property called StartFromCurrentNode which when set to false achieves the same menu on all pages.

-->